# Ajax is not working in codeigniter 4 when call the controller

Tags: html, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just want to make sure this ajax is working to call my controller. But when i click the button nothing happened. Thank you

My view :

```
<input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number">
<button type="button" id="sendotp" name="sendotp" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
```

My AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sendotp').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

          var phonenumber = $("input[name='phonenumber']").val();

          $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/register',
                type:'post',
              dataType:'json',
                data: {
                  phonenumber:phonenumber
                },
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
  });   
});
```

My Controller :

```
public function register()
    {   
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){

            $phonenumber = $this->request->getPost('phonenumber');
            echo $phonenumber;
        }
        return view('register/register');
    }
```

My Routes :

```
$routes->match(['get', 'post'],'/register', 'Home::register');
```

Comment: When you open your developer options in your browser and check the network tab what does it show for that request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you have you success event empty. So nothing happening is the expected behavior. If you're returning a view in your controller, you must do something with it in your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

marco answer sufficient.

You need also to add

```
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

in your ajax call in JQuery

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/register',
                type:'post',
              dataType:'json',
               headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: {
                  phonenumber:phonenumber
                },
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
```

and in your controller check if its ajax call first before processing anything.

```
if ($this->request->isAJAX())
{
}
```

Please refer to [isAjax](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html?highlight=isajax) and refer to [Ajax JQuery](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ajax.html?highlight=isajax)

this is the proper way to handle ajax calls in Codeigniter4 .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I fixed it Like this:
in `app/Config/Filter.php` make this change:

```
public $globals = [
        'before' => [
                'csrf' => ['except' => ['your route or api']]
        ]
];
```