# Codeigniter 4 - AJAX does not send data to and get response from Controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4, ajaxform

Last time, I met an issue with emojis in Codeigniter 4 and it got solved. Thanks to Marleen.
Now I am encountering AJAX.
I followed [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6lrQxoo_Qs&list=PLRheCL1cXHrsGt2A51oS1JdQ9j4mBEvui&index=3), which insert data into DB without refreshing page using AJAX.

I can make insert, update, delete using Model and Controller. However, when playing with AJAX, it did not bring any signs to keep going.

I would like to make a search function with AJAX, so I started with the basic learning which inserting data to DB. But it failed me.

Please, help me to solve this.

I have tried adding following things:
1 - Adding [Accessing the request](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#accessing-the-request) guided in Codeigniter 4.
2 - Adding [headers](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ajax.html?highlight=isajax#jquery) to ajax.
3 - Adding [csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456729/ajax-is-not-working-in-codeigniter-4-when-call-the-controller) guided in this last comment.
4 - In the Congif/Filters.php file, I added csrf as

```
        'post' => ['csrf'],
    ];
```

5 - Insted of using `return $this->response->setJSON($data);`, I tried `echo json_encode($data);`.
6 - I defined my localhost url in my script `var base_url = "http://localhost/ajax/` and add in the ajax url as `url: base_url + "testajax/store",`.

My test_ajax view:

```
<?= $this->extend('layouts/base'); ?>

<?= $this->section('title'); ?>
    <?= $page_title; ?>
<?= $this->endSection();?> 

<?= $this->section("content");?>

    <!-- Main -->
    <section>
        <div class="main-container">
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="studentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Student</h5>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <span class="text-danger" id="error_name"></span>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Full name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <span class="text-danger" id="error_email"></span>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Emailt">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <span class="text-danger" id="error_phone"></span>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Phone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <span class="text-danger" id="error_course"></span>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control course" placeholder="Course">
                        </div>
                            
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ajaxstudent-save">Save changes</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <!------------- My Box ----------------->
            <div class="box animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                <div class="row d-flex path">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">User Profiles</h3>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h4>
                                    Ajax Test with dump Students data Table
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal">Add Student</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!------------- End - My Box ----------------->

        </div>
    </section>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','.ajaxstudent-save', function(){
                
                
                if($.trim($('.name').val().length) == 0)
                {
                    error_name = "Please, enter your full name.";
                    $('#error_name').text(error_name);
                }
                else
                {
                    error_name = "";
                    $('#error_name').text(error_name);  
                }
                
                if($.trim($('.email').val().length) == 0)
                {
                    error_email = "Please, enter your email.";
                    $('#error_email').text(error_email);
                }
                else
                {
                    error_email = "";
                    $('#error_email').text(error_email); 
                }
                
                if($.trim($('.phone').val().length) == 0)
                {
                    error_phone = "Please, enter your phone number.";
                    $('#error_phone').text(error_phone);
                }
                else
                {
                    error_phone = "";
                    $('#error_phone').text(error_phone); 
                }
                
                if($.trim($('.course').val().length) == 0)
                {
                    error_course = "Please, enter your course.";
                    $('#error_course').text(error_course);
                }
                else
                {
                    error_course = "";
                    $('#error_course').text(error_course);
                }
                
                
                if(error_name != '' || error_email != '' || error_phone != '' || error_course != '')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var data = {
                        'name': $('.name').val(),
                        'email': $('.email').val(),
                        'phone': $('.phone').val(),
                        'course': $('.course').val(),
                    };
                    
                    var base_url = "http://localhost/ajax/";
                    $.ajax({
                       url: base_url + "testajax/store",
                       method: "POST",
                       headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                       data: data,
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function(response){
                           
                           $('#studentModal').modal('hide');
                           $('#studentModal').find('input').val('');
                           
                           alertify.set('notifier','position','top-right');
                           alertify.success(response.status);
                           console.log(response.status);
                       }
                    });
                }
                
                
            });
        });
        
    </script>

    
<?= $this->endSection(); ?>
```

My TestAjax Controller:

```
<?php

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Scripting/PHPClass.php to edit this template
 */

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\AjaxStudentModel;

/**
 * Description of TestAjax
 *
 * @author phamv
 */
class TestAjax extends BaseController {
    //put your code here
    
    public function index() {
        if(!session()->has('loggedin_user'))
        {
            return redirect()->to(base_url().'/login/');
        }
        
        
        $data = [
            'page_title' => 'Test Ajax',
            
        ];
        return view('test_ajax',$data);
    }
    
    
    public function store() {
        
        if($this->request->isAJAX())
        {
            $students = new AjaxStudentModel();
            $data = [
                'name' => $this->request->getPost('name'),
                'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
                'phone' => $this->request->getPost('phone'),
                'course' => $this->request->getPost('course'),
            ];

            $students->save($data);
            $data = ['status'=>'Student added successfully!'];
            return $this->response->setJSON($data);
        }
    }
    
}
```

And my AjaxStudentModel below:

```
<?php

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Scripting/PHPClass.php to edit this template
 */

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

/**
 * Description of AjaxStudentModel
 *
 * @author phamv
 */
class AjaxStudentModel extends Model {
    //put your code here
    protected $table = 'students';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['name','email','phone','course'];
    
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, share your Controller, View, and JavaScript/AJAX source code snippets.

Comment: I updated my Controller, View and Model for the ajax above. Please have a look at them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I assume that you're asking why you're not getting the alertify popup with the response from the server saying "Student added successfully!"

The difference between your code and the code in the video is that you are wrapping the input fields in a `<form>` tag, and using a button with `type="submit` instead of `type="button"`.

When you click on a form's submit button, it's default behaviour is to submit the form and reload the (new) page. Since you haven't specified an `action` attribute on your form tag, your form will submit to/reload the current page.

So when you click the "Save changes" button, your ajax request is sent, and at the end of the javascript function, the page is submitted and reloaded because that's the default behaviour for a submit button in a form.

The success part of the ajax method then never gets executed, because by the time a response is returned, the page that sent the request no longer exists, so it can't handle the response and show the success message.

To do the same as in the video:

- remove the `<form>` tags:

  ```
    <!-- <form method="post"> -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="text-danger" id="error_name"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Full name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="text-danger" id="error_email"></span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Emailt">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="text-danger" id="error_phone"></span>
        <input type="number" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="text-danger" id="error_course"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control course" placeholder="Course">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ajaxstudent-save">Save changes</button>
    <!-- </form> -->
  ```
- change `<button type="submit">` to `<button type="button">`:

  ```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ajaxstudent-save">Save changes</button>
  ```

Or if you want to keep your form and submit button, you can also do one of the following:

- add an `e` argument to the event handler ( `function(e)` ) and start with `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from executing its default behaviour of submitting and reloading:

  ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.ajaxstudent-save', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($.trim($('.name').val().length) == 0)
            {
                error_name = "Please, enter your full name.";
                $('#error_name').text(error_name);
            }
            else
            {
                error_name = "";
                $('#error_name').text(error_name);  
            }

            // etc
  ```
- return `false` after sending the ajax request, returning `false` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault()` + `e.preventPropagation()`:

  ```
    if(error_name != '' || error_email != '' || error_phone != '' || error_course != '')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var data = {
            'name': $('.name').val(),
            'email': $('.email').val(),
            'phone': $('.phone').val(),
            'course': $('.course').val(),
        };

        var base_url = "http://localhost/ajax/";
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "testajax/store",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){

                $('#studentModal').modal('hide');
                $('#studentModal').find('input').val('');

                alertify.set('notifier','position','top-right');
                alertify.success(response.status);
                console.log(response.status);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
  ```

---

Also make sure you've included the css and javascript for the alertify library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/css/alertify.min.css" integrity="sha512-IXuoq1aFd2wXs4NqGskwX2Vb+I8UJ+tGJEu/Dc0zwLNKeQ7CW3Sr6v0yU3z5OQWe3eScVIkER4J9L7byrgR/fA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js" integrity="sha512-JnjG+Wt53GspUQXQhc+c4j8SBERsgJAoHeehagKHlxQN+MtCCmFDghX9/AcbkkNRZptyZU4zC8utK59M5L45Iw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And remove the `csrf` config you've added to `Config/Filters.php`

Comment: Thank you so so so much, Marleen!
It's solved. 
Now I am back to learning Ajax in Codeigniter 4.
Happy New Year!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy new year to you too!